# Open encrypted image as Bitmap C#

Tags: c#, encryption, bitmap, data-hiding

I need to perform data hiding in encrypted image. To perform data hiding i need to have bitmap Image. But i don't know how to save the image as bitmap.

Below is my encryption code.

```
public void EncryptFile(string source, string destination)
{
    string sKey = "super545";
    FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(source, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    FileStream fsEncrypted = new FileStream(destination, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

    DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
    DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
    DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
    ICryptoTransform desencrypt = DES.CreateEncryptor();
    CryptoStream cryptostream = new CryptoStream(fsEncrypted, desencrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    byte[] bytearrayinput = new byte[fsInput.Length - 1];

    fsInput.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
    cryptostream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
    cryptostream.Close();
    fsInput.Close();
    fsEncrypted.Close();
}
```

This is called like:

```
EncryptFile(originalimage, output);
```

`output` is a string variable with the path to store the encrypted image.

How can I call the function to run the encryption?

I receive the error the parameter is invalid when i hit this line:

```
Bitmap bitmap3 = new Bitmap(output);
```

Comment: It appears the code is encrypting the entire bitmap file, not the data contained within. This is why it's failing, you've encrypted the file format and it doesn't understand what it is anymore.

Comment: i have tried to exclude the headers :-

 byte[] bytearrayinput = new byte[fsInput.Length - 54];

still cannot open the image.

Comment: there are a few things i'd like to point out here... excluding the headers SHOULD mean: copy them to the output file WITHOUT encrypting them... not just taking 54 byte less from the input file ...54 byte may be the header size, but maybe you also want to leave the color tables / color masks intact...and of course the whole thing will only work with uncompressed bitmaps, so you might want to test if the header field biCompression is either 0 or 3 ... if not, reject the image or decompress it first...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you are trying to do is pretty close to this:

```
public void EncryptFile(string source, string destination)
{
    string sKey = "super545";
    FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(source, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    FileStream fsEncrypted = new FileStream(destination, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

    //Consider to use something else, DES is dead
    DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

    //use some key derivation function like pbkdf2 instead
    DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);

    //should be random, may be fixed ONLY for testing purposes
    DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);

    ICryptoTransform desencrypt = DES.CreateEncryptor();
    CryptoStream cryptostream = new CryptoStream(fsEncrypted, desencrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    //byte[] bytearrayinput = new byte[fsInput.Length - 1]; // what do you need that big buffer for anyways?
    //fsInput.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
    //cryptostream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);

    byte[] headerBuffer = new byte[54]; // buffer for our bmp header ... without any color tables or masks

    //No need for lots of checks in a proof of concept
    fsInput.Read(headerBuffer, 0, headerBuffer.Length);
    var biCompression = BitConverter.ToInt32(headerBuffer, 30); //get biComp from header

    if (biCompression != 0 && biCompression != 3)
    {
        throw new Exception("Compression is not in the correct format");
    }

    //The buffer is copied without any encryption
    fsEncrypted.Write(headerBuffer, 0, headerBuffer.Length);

    //copy the rest and encrypt it ... don't care about color tables and masks for now
    //and let's just hope plaintext and ciphertext have the right size
    fsInput.CopyTo(cryptostream);

    cryptostream.Close();
    fsInput.Close();
    fsEncrypted.Close();
}
```

Comment: Consider using `using` statements on the objects that implement `IDisposable`, i.e. the `stream`s,  to make sure that they are closed and disposed of correctly. It is also best practice and so good to promote.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot..it solved my problem. The code is working :)
i will analyse your code and learn from there.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder - it is a PoC and meant to be as close to Abby's Code as possible ... if we start to apply coding guidelines here then like 80% of the changes will be about anything but Abby's question ... mean enough that you edited out the fun stuff... ;-(

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 the fun stuff (although I did like it) is noise on StackOverflow. And I do know that but that's a major problem in some peoples code... i.e. memory leaks. If you want to leave it as such, I usually add an improvements to be made section or similar so the OP can see how they can improve their code, just an idea but it does help. Also I did upvote your answer :)

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 For an example on how you can do this, see my answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34268896/4631427